# Optional hell in Swift?

Tags: swift, option-type

How can I properly handle optionals especially when it is multi-level optional?

For example,

```
let html = String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8)

if let string = html {
    let doc = try? SwiftSoup.parse(html)
    let links = try? doc?.select("a").array().map{try? $0.attr("href")}
}
// links!![0]! is crazy
```

Constant `links` is like below: optional of optional array of optional strings
`Optional(Optional([Optional("abc.com"), Optional("def.com")]))`

Is there a pattern which is more proper than `do-try-catch` block or optional binding?

Comment: What is *not proper* with `do - catch`?

Comment: "optional of optional array of optional strings" There's your problem. Make that into it's own Type that manages it's own validity.

Comment: @vadian Sorry It's more of a 'simple' than 'proper'

Comment: @PeejWeej Could you tell me more specifically?

Comment: I'd look for the most efficient solution, not for the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Replace most of the `try?` with `try` in a `do/catch`. You only need one `do/catch` with your multiple `try`. Use `if let` more. Use `flatMap` instead of `map`.

```
if let html = String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8) {
    do {
        let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
        let links = try doc.select("a").array().flatMap { try? $0.attr("href") }
    } catch {
        // Uh-oh
    }
}
```

I can't test this so this may not be perfect but it should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Alternately, you can just use `map` instead of `flatMap` and replace `try?` inside the closure with `try`. That will cause you to bail if anything inside the closure fails instead of just removing it from the array, which depending on what you want might be desirable.

Comment: Also, if you're using Swift 4.1, that will need to be `compactMap` rather than `flatMap`

Answer (score 0):

You can chain several `if let` statements in a single command, like this:

```
if let string = html, let doc = try? SwiftSoup.parse(html) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got several choices, none of which are really more "proper" than the others, so it's a matter of taste. But I'd probably do one of:

A compound `if` statement:

```
if let responseData = response.data,
    let string = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8),
    let doc = try? SwiftSoup.parse(html),
    let links = try? doc.select("a").array().compactMap({ try? $0.attr("href") }) {
    // do something with links, any nil will get filtered out from the array
    // (if using earlier than Swift 4.1, use flatMap instead of compactMap)
}
```

`guard` statements:

```
guard let responseData = response.data else { /* bail somehow */ }
guard let string = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8) else { /* bail somehow */ }
... etc ...
```

Alternately, one long `guard` statement written like the `if` statement above.

Or, y'know, just use a good old-fashioned `do`/`try`/`catch` block.